# ubuntu mate 16.04 mate tweak doesn't allow vertical workspace

Tags: compiz, ubuntu-mate, ubuntu-tweak

I enabled compiz in mate tweak, but it does not allow create vertical workspace. I can do it when I choose other windows manager, but I would like to use compiz. I wanto 6 workspaces with 2 vertical rows.